# Why is TouchableOpacity half hidden when passed back in {} in react native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

React native on `iOS` shows the `Touchable Opacity` weirdly.  It is rendered in such way that the button is half buried into the title.  Style and creation should be right.  I was following a tutorial.  Copied and pasted the code from the instructor, but it is still going wrong.  I wrapped the button in another styled view section and everything was fine, I wonder why this is the case.

```
<View>
    {function()}
</View>

function() {return <Button />}
```

Button:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#007aff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#007aff',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }
};

export { Button };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code of the view in which is the button please ?

Comment: It is in the question.  Sorry if it is not clear.  The second big chunk of code is for button.